# Hide the suitebar and ribbon used in Excel web apps - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, office-web-apps

Has anyone had success in hiding or removing the suitebar and ribbon used when you click on a document? The page is `wopiframe.aspx`.

Tried via the masterpage by using css of some element but no luck.

Comment: It's impossible to edit it since it's a layouts page.

Comment: thanks but does it use the same masterpage? I have tried using css to hide it but no luck